# Рисование "ушек" стрелки относительно линии

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-canvas, wpf-шаблоны

В приложении на WPF есть Canvas на котором пользователь может ставить точки и соединять их. Таким образом он строит граф. Связи у графа могут быть ненаправленные, однонаправленные и двунаправленные.

Для ненаправленной связи рисуется просто линия

[image: Ненаправленная связь]

Но для направленной связи нужно рисовать стрелку, причем которая будет следовать за вершиной.

[image: Направленная связь]

[image: Направленная связь]

Сам механизм следования линии за вершиной готов.

**Проблема заключается в** рисовании "ушек" стрелок относительно линии. Подскажите какие есть варианты сделать такое? Или можно сделать это как-то по другому?

Код рисования линии

```
<!--Отображение связей.-->
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Connections}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <Canvas/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Line 
                            X1="{Binding X1}" 
                            Y1="{Binding Y1}" 
                            X2="{Binding X2}" 
                            Y2="{Binding Y2}" 
                            Stroke="Black" 
                            StrokeThickness="{Binding Thickness}">
                            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseDown">
                                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.ClickOnGraphElement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                                </i:EventTrigger>
                            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        </Line>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Банальная геометрия. Вектор направления к другой точке известен. Берёте этот вектор, укорачиваете до длины стрелки, поворачиваете на небольшой угол с центром поворота на острие стрелки. Повторяете то же самое, только с отрицательным углом. Рисуете линии ну или треугольник по этим точкам. Кстати `Interaction.Triggers` это костыль. Обычно его используют те, кто плохо знает WPF и его контролы. А именно вы не знаете про контрол `Thumb`, изучите его.

Comment: @aepot, связь не должна являться объектом Thumb, она должна быть линией. Здесь Interaction.Triggers я использую для отслеживания нажатия и получения экземпляра объекта связи

Comment: Вообще механизм `Thumb`+`Adorner` - это штатное средство перемещения/выделения чего-либо мышью. Не знаю, с чего вы взяли что что-то там не должно быть чем-то.

Comment: Может потому что проект делаю я, а не кто то другой?  И я сам решаю какой объект «кем» должен являться

Comment: В этом плане да, решайте, спору нет. Я просто намекнул, что вы пошли не самым простым путём. Ваше право прислушаться или нет.

Comment: А так, сойзайте юзерконтрол, например `Arrow`, заведите в нём свойства `DependencyProperty` с координатами начала и конца и `bool`-свойтвами, которые будут указывать, есть стрелка на оконечности или нет. Внутри рисуйте линию и считайте точки для отрисовки стрелок. Добавьте `DP` для `Stroke` и `StrokeThickness` по вкусу. В теории можно от `Line` отнаследоваться, но это уже решайте сами.